# Diagonalization problems (eigenvalues and vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to diagonalize the following matrices:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\qquad B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

For matrix $A$, I find an eigenvalue of $1$ with algebraic multiplicity of $2$. I find, though, that the dimension of its eigenspace consists of $1$ vector? Can I still construct a matrix to diagonalize with somehow?

For matrix B, I get the same scenario for eigenvalues (value of $1$ repeated twice), but am unsure if my eigenspace, consisting of $(1,0)$, is correct? Then again, I am left in the same situation.

Are those matrices un-diagonalizable? (spelling?) Can someone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: But the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $x^2+1,$ why do you say that $B$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial I got for B is (1-x)^2..

Comment: Calculation: $$char(B)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1-x & 2\\-1&-1-x\end{pmatrix}=x^2-1+2=x^2+1.$$

Comment: Yeah you are right, I always have trouble with dealing with factorizing the polynomial to find the eigenvalues. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. And the pleasure is mine.

Comment: On a last note, does B still have only one eigenvalue, which would now be -1? Therefore it wouldn't be diagonalizable, even though it appears to be given the other answers. I think something is going over my head here haha..

Comment: No, the second has eigenvalues $\pm i$ and is diagonalizable as my answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The first is not diagonalizable, but we can use the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). We get:

$$A = PJP^{-1} =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The second is diagonalizable and we get:

$$A = PJP^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i-1 & -i-1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -i & 0 \\
 0 & i \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2 i} & \frac{i+1}{2 i} \\
 -\frac{1}{2 i} & \frac{i-1}{2 i} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: When you say "you can use Jordan Normal Form," that means that the matrix is not diagonalizable, right?

Comment: Ok.  (My LA class did not cover Jordan normal form, so I didn't know if that could be considered a special case of diagonal, or not...)

Comment: Here is a nice write-up for the 2x2 case: http://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/old/Math_54-05/webfoils/jordan.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you have an eigenvalue with multiplicity n, then you must have n linearly independent eigenvectors from that eigenvalue in order for the matrix to be diagonalizable.